# Confused with Session's getAttribute and setAttribute methods

Tags: java, servlets

I used the `session.set/getAttribute()` to pass my `HashMap` to another servlet. On my next servlet, I will add a value to my `HashMap` but when I search for the value, it can't be read. Why is it not working?

I am setting it as follows:

```
session.setAttribute("itemList", itemList);
```

And I am retrieving it as follows:

```
HashMap itemList = (HashMap)session.getAttribute("itemList");
itemList.put(stockNo, item);
session.setAttribute("itemList", itemList);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Just check in the AddtheEntry servlet whether it provides new session or old one.

Comment: Note that the setAttribute call in the second servlet is unnecessary. The changes will be reflected in the referenced object anyway. This is Java, not PHP or some non-OO language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session.setAttribute("itemList", itemList); //is this correct???
```

In your statement above, you have just associated "itemList" (identifier) to itemList (object). This means, if you want to make a reference later on to this itemList object, you just need to quote the "itemList" identifier.

Java API is your good friend. You should have figured out this pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

session.setAttribute("itemList", itemList); //IS THIS CORRECT? --- this is the way you are setting it

HashMap itemList = (HashMap)session.getAttribute("hashM"); --- this is the way you are retrieving it

Use the same key "itemList" at both the places.